# Android Close keyboard smoothly

Tags: android, android-keypad

I am using the following code to hide the soft keyboard from screen

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                mSearchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

When the keyboard closes a white box appears in the space that had been covered it for a small period of time, can this be avoided?

Comment: what's the version of OS you're using it??

Comment: @kAnNaN I have tried it on android versions 2.3 to 4.4

Comment: Not sure but try this line `overridePendingTransition(0, 0);` after your code.

Comment: @Kedarnath That did not work out

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue, a white box still appears when the soft keyboard is closed

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had set windowSoftInputMode property to adjustResize for the activity in manifest.